# How to know if a particular application is currently running?

Tags: android

I am trying to build an application that can detect if the Messaging application is currently running so I can foreground one of my activity to prompt the user for a password.

What I have done:

1)Created a service that starts running after startup.

Now, what is confusing me:

1)Is the messaging application a process, a thread, a task, or something else?
2)What is its package name that i should write to check if running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you can check if an app is running you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213851/1183280

Now you have to know the package name. As there are many different messaging applications for android (stock Android, HTC Sense, Handcent SMS, etc.) you will have to check more than just one. I think the one for the stock app is "com.android.mms".

Comment: can u please provide me any link where i could find details about the names of different sms packages  ? Just informing that my application is only for sonyericsson xperia android phone