# call method while application closed

Tags: android, call

How can I call a method **while my application is closed** on Android?

I've tried:
`Onpause()`, `OnDestroy()`, and `OnStop()`. With no luck.

What I want is receiving something from the database and do my reaction 
based upon when the application is closed.

Comment: You could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32586248/3743245

Comment: thank you for reply :
Exactly what I want is that the application by the notification changed when a certain value outside the application even if the application is closed

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use broadcast or service to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base activity (BaseActivity class) from which all your activities would have to be derived. Then inside BaseActivity.onCreate - you would increase some SharedPreferences counter, and inside BaseActivity.onDestroy you would decrease it.  Now when that counter is equal to zero, you might assume your application is closed - but the process might still run in the background.

> What I want is receiving something from the database

now I assume you already know how to "receive something from database". This could be background Service, where you could check SharedPreferences and do your processing.

Comment: thank you for reply :
yes Actually I have been receiving thing from the database, but I will try your idea for BaseActivity  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is the trigger?

Part 1 : Intent - 
By example, you can set an alarm, that launch an Intent.

Part 2 : Broadcast Receiver - You must create a Broadcast Receiver (which reacts to an intent).

Part 3 : Service - The Broadcast Intent will launch a service that will execute when the application is not open.

Comment: thank you for reply :
Please can you give me more information about the Broadcast ?

Comment: An example : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers. Official documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Intent and Broadcast Receiver are the basics of android, you can find a lot of documentation about it on => Google

Comment: Thank you :
Well I understand now, but Broadcast wont's happened to the activation of such receive a text message or change the settings in the phone.
but in my case just i'll change value in my database any idea ?