# How can i check if an app is open in Android?

Tags: android

I see that question: [How can i check if an app running in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-in-android)

But i want to get name of opened application ( user see ) live in android.

I want to run a background service to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the running Application package name using this function:

```
public String foregroundPackage() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
        return componentInfo.getPackageName();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i run your code, i get only **com.l.launcher** in any apps.

Comment: i don't know how are you calling the function, but i can assure you it returns the top application package name.

Comment: I have a loop function each 5 seconds for example, and I putted your code in this loop to get name. only in my app, I get correct name ( **com.example.test** ), but on other application, i get this: **com.l.launcher** :(

Comment: hmmmm, i disabled my **L Launcher**, but know when i open (for example) chrome, i get **com.android.launcher** :(