# Checking if an application is running - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to know if an app (not my app. other app ex. gmail) is running or not.Is it possible using kotlin?

Comment: Here is how you do it in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-on-android What specific problems did you encounter when porting that code to Kotlin? It should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Affirmative. It's very much possible to detect if an app, other than your app too, is running or not. You need to use [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) to fetch the information. You can use the following code snippet for achieving the desired list:

```
val pm = this.getPackageManager()

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)

val list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
for (rInfo in list) {
    Log.w("List of Installed Applications:", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString())
}
```

If you visit the link mentioned above, you'll find out all the available nested classes [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#summary). For example, to fetch the running task, use `RunningAppProcessInfo` like [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html). You can also check if it's in the background, foreground etc. Please refer to this [link](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2011/05/way-to-check-whether-application-is.html) to get sample codes.

Comment: This lists installed applications, not running applications.

Comment: @Enselic I've included the link, please read the whole answer, all the required information nested classes are listed in that link I provided: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#summary

Comment: For example: `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo` - Information you can retrieve about a running process - says the links. There's also `ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo`- Information you can retrieve about tasks that the user has most recently started or visited. All the codes, according to what you require is well documented in the provided link in the answer. Please check again. I've just provided one snippet of code, can be changed into any the nested classes to fetch the associated information.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, links to resources that can be used to figure out the answer is not enough; the answer on this site must be self-contained. Links are only for reference, not a substitute for an elaborate answer.

Comment: I've edited the answer to detecting the running processes too, please check and add another answer if mine doesn't fill up the purpose. And also, I still don't think coding the whole android (and then maybe sharing a github url to the entire project) is required to answer such a question on a utility method like this. Please enlighten me if I'm wrong or what else I can add up to this answer to make it better for everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately RunningAppProcessInfo only return my app. It does not work for other apps. Any other solution? I'm using android p.