# Can you write an app that records the screen of a specific app in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm try to make an android app that records specify app's screen and audio.
How can I record the screen?

Comment: Please elaborate your query in detail. There's available API for Screen Recording on Android.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example for using MediaProjection API for screen recording on Android: [GoogleSource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/projection/MediaProjectionDemo.java) You can add Service class to run in a background check when a certain app package is opened. Here's an example to check an app running on Android. [Stackoverflow Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-on-android)